# Cisco Composite "Catastrophic Failure" using ODBC Driver

Tags: excel, ado, data-virtualization, vba

I have a working Excel 2013 solution, running fine on Windows 7 Pro.  It is a VBA solution connecting to Cisco Composite using the Composite version 7.0 ODBC Driver.

I moved to Windows 10 Pro on a new laptop, and have installed the same ODBC Driver.  I have tested I can create a USER DSN and connect to Composite via this driver...all works.

However, my macro enabled solution is now failing...but working fine on my old laptop.

I am declaring the connection string as below:

> Public Const strProXP As String = "Driver={Cisco Information Server
>   7.0};Server=cis.mycompany.net;Port=9401;Domain=composite;dataSource=myds;user=ds_service;password=mypassword;validateRemoteHostname=false;connectTimeout=3000;enableFastExec=false;"
>   Public

This is working on my old laptop.  Now, same spreadsheet, same driver - I get this message when connecting : "Catastrophic Failure".

```
Public connCDBP As ADODB.Connection
Public cmdCDBP As ADODB.Command
Public rstCDBP As ADODB.Recordset
Public fldCDBP As ADODB.Field


Public Sub XP_Open_Database()
    Dim errH As cErrHandler
    Dim strConnection As String

    Set errH = New cErrHandler
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    strConnection = strProXP

    Set connXP = New ADODB.Connection
    connXP.ConnectionString = strConnection
    connXP.CommandTimeout = 0
    connXP.Open  'Error Here
    Set cmdXP = New ADODB.Command
    cmdXP.ActiveConnection = connXP
    cmdXP.CommandTimeout = 0

Normal_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    errH.Action_Error "mdlData", "XP_Open_Database", err, True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you put a break in the code, does the value of strConnection match what you expect?

Comment: yes, this all works on another laptop, connection string is OK.